Clarifications sought on the paper on the semigroup associated with a free polynomial by Ali Abbas and Abdallah Assi
I have three questions regarding the proof of Proposition 4 on page 4 of this paper here. For those interested in addressing these questions, please refer to some definitions in the first two or three pages of the paper. As a quick note, let $M_i$ denote the leading monomial of $y_k - y_1$.
In this proposition, we aim to prove that $L(y_1) = L(M_1, \dots, M_h)$ (where the definitions of $M_i$ and $y_1$ are provided in the paper). In the first part of the proof, we show that $L(M_1, \dots, M_h) \subseteq L(y_1)$. Regarding this part, I have the following questions:

We have $\theta$ as an $L$-automorphism of $L_n$ with $\theta(y_1) = y_1$. Therefore, for every element $f \in L(y_1)$, we have $\theta(f) = f$. However, is it necessarily true that if $\theta(f) = f$, then $f \in L(y_1)$? The authors state in the third line of the proof that $\theta(\underline{x}^{\frac{p}{n}}) = \underline{x}^{\frac{p}{n}}$, and hence $\underline{x}^{\frac{p}{n}} \in L(y_1)$. They also rely on this fact in the second part of the proof.

Another question in this part of the proof concerns the authors' statement that $M_1, \dots, M_h$ are monomials of $y_1$. Why is this true? For example, if we consider $y_k = \underline{x}^{\frac{(2,2,\dots,2)}{n}} - \underline{x}^{\frac{(1,1,\dots,1)}{n}}$ and $y_1 = \underline{x}^{\frac{(2,2,\dots,2)}{n}}$, then $y_k - y_1 = -\underline{x}^{\frac{(1,1,\dots,1)}{n}}$, and it's leading monomail is $\underline{x}^{\frac{(1,1,\dots,1)}{n}}$ which is not a monomial of $y_1$.


In the second part of the proof, I have the following question:
Why is it that if $\theta(y_1)$ is different from $y_1$, then $\theta(M_i)$ must be different from $M_i$?
